# How to add the elements of form and get data dynamically in Angular?

Tags: angular

[image: Requirement]This is my html code in which I am adding thisform div on click of button, my requirement is to add the unitprice and quantity and get the total amount dynamically , but the problem is here that whenever I am trying to calculate the totalprice it is getting added the same in every div  . Any sort of help is appreciated .

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg active" (click)="todoList($event)"
              value="AddItem" style="text-align: center; margin: 0 inherit;" />
            <div class="form-inline">
              &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

              <div class="form-inline" *ngFor="let container of containers">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label>ProductName:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="productname" value="{{productname}}" class="form-control"
                      [(ngModel)]="productname" maxlength="4" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label>Quantity:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="{{quantity}}" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="quantity"
                      maxlength="4" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label>UnitPrice:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="unitprice" value="{{unitprice}}" class="form-control"
                      [(ngModel)]="unitprice" maxlength="4" (ngModelChange)="findsumdata($event)"
                      onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label>TotalAmount:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="totalamount" value="{{ this.totalprice}}"
                      class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="totalprice" maxlength="4"
                      onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')" disabled>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

This my ts file :-

```
Component.ts :- 


     todoList(event) {
    this.containers.push(this.containers.length);
  }

  findsumdata(event) {
    this.totalprice = this.unitprice * this.quantity
      console.log(this.totalprice)
  }

  removefields(event) {
    this.containers.slice(this.containers[this.containers.length - 1])
    this.containers.pop()
  }
```

Comment: Hi Brother is can help with but you share any example of UI what you planning to do

Comment: I have added the Image @harkesh

Comment: yes  same thing am talking about using formArray  you as achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Hi Am Not 100% Clear with your questions but I feel like,

You asking about, `Dynamically adding controls`

If you using Reactive form then by using `FormArray` its will help to create dynamic forms

you can search on google about `FromArray` or also refer this link

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-form-array/

Answer (score 0):

Hi as @harkesh Kumar stated, I think you would have to create the forms dynamically.

Once it is dynamically created, you can loop through them in a FormArray

Comment: Thanks for support if you thing am right please up vote my answer